# How do I create a MutableList<MutableList<Int>> from MutableList<MutableList<Boolean>> of the same size in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am wondering how can I create a `newmatrix = MutableList<MutableList<Int>>` of the same size as a given `matrix = MutableList<MutableList<Boolean>>`. In particular I want the `newmatrix` to be zeros, which I can do by doing loops.
First idea was to do it like this:

```
var newmatrix = matrix
// tworzymy macierz równą zero
for (k in 0..matrix.indices.last) {
    for (l in 0..matrix[0].indices.last) {
        newmatrix[k][l] = 0
    }
}
```

But of course it does not work, because it says that `newmatrix` has type `Boolean`, not `Int`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write an extension function that converts a `MutableList<Boolean>` to a `MutableList<Int>` and then use a `forEach` on the list of lists in order to convert every item:

```
// extension function for an Int-representation of a Boolean-list
fun MutableList<Boolean>.toIntList(): MutableList<Int> {
    var result: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf()
    this.forEach { it -> if (it) { result.add(1) } else { result.add(0) } }
    return result
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    // example Boolean-matrix
    var matrix: MutableList<MutableList<Boolean>> = mutableListOf(
            mutableListOf(true, true, true),
            mutableListOf(false, false, false),
            mutableListOf(false, true, false),
            mutableListOf(true, false, true)
    )
    // provide the structure for the result
    val newMatrix: MutableList<MutableList<Int>> = mutableListOf()
    // for each Boolean-list in the source list add the result of toIntList() to the result
    matrix.forEach { it -> newMatrix.add(it.toIntList()) }
    // print the source list
    println(matrix)
    // print the resulting Int list
    println(newMatrix)
}
```

Output:

```
[[true, true, true], [false, false, false], [false, true, false], [true, false, true]]
[[1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]]
```

There may be different and even better ways to convert, but this appears sufficient.